# Does iCloud save deleted pictures from your camera and photo stream?

Tags: icloud, photos

Does iCloud save deleted pictures from your camera and photo stream?

For example: If you saved a picture from Google but deleted it from your camera and the photo stream does it still save it to iCloud?

Comment: possible duplicate of [icloud saving photos does it?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147039/icloud-saving-photos-does-it)

Comment: you have to specifically sync to icloud right? –

Answer (score -1):

Heard that iCloud automatically backs up your iOS device information daily over Wi-Fi when your device is turned on, locked, and connected to a power source. On your iOS device, go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup, then turn on iCloud Backup.